# Apple MDM Push Notification: Which key and certificate to use?

Tags: ios, mdm

I've been at this for about 12 hours.  All of the google links are purple that have anything to do with MDM.  I swear to all that matters that I've tried everything.  I've regenerated the Vendor and Customer CSRs, keys, etc a dozen times and cannot get a push notification to work.

Here's what I've done:

1. Created a vendor CSR, exported the private key as vendor.p12
2. Logged into Apple Provisioning Portal and generated the MDM CSR Certificate
3. Downloaded that certificate and called it vendor.cer
4. Run this command "openssl pkcs12 -in vendor.p12 -nocerts -out vendor.pem"
5. I then created a second CSR in Keychain Utility called customer.csr
6. I used the cool python script found here: https://github.com/grinich/mdmvendorsign
7. I ran the command for this script: "python mdm_vendor_sign.py  --csr customer.csr --key vendor.key --mdm vendor.cer"
8. This generated a plist cert request that I then uploaded to https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/
9. I downloaded the certificate and called it client-push.pem
10. I attempted to check and see if it works by running this command:
    "openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert push.pem -key vendor.pem".  This gives me the error "error setting private key
    67028:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:406:"

---

So my question is: what key and certificate combination do I use to send push notifications?  It makes sense that I would use the VENDOR key and the CUSTOMER's cert since I'm never going to have the CUSTOMER's private key, but is this wrong?

When I use the customer's KEY and CERT it looks like it works by printing a whole bunch of stuff but at the very top it says "verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate".  Besides, how will I get the customer's private key?

The last thing to try was the vendor's cert and key, which seemed to work the exact same as using the customer's key and cert.

Which combination is the correct way?

On a side note, do I need to do anything to convert the "data" push token to a regular push token?  It says it's base64 encoded.  Do I need to decode it?

**UPDATE**

I've read that the token is a 32 byte base64 encoded string.  I'm using PHP to send the push notification os I figure a bin2hext(base64_decode(Token)) will work.  It looks legitimate when I do that at least.  Sill no push notification.

I've also tried all possible combinations and the only time I can get it to send the notification without any errors i when I use both the vendor Key and Cert in the same PEM file.  The message still never arrives.  I've also tried (and successfully generated) the PEM cert file from identity.apple.com/pushcert quite a few times.  It says it worked on that page.

I'm using the Push library for the Laravel framework.  All it asks for is a certificate file, the push server host, and a pem password.

I'm getting this error when I try to use the pem file generated from identity.apple.com/pushcert:

stream_socket_client(): Unable to set local cert chain file `/Users/neb/Dev/www/cgmdm/trunk/app/certificates/MDM.p12'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer

Comment: Hi Benjamin ..Have you setup MDM server for iOS devices successfully ? I am also trying to setup MDM server using this code  https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server . I am sending command on device but nothing happens. Please help.